# Why isn't my custom jQuery function working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm following [this tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery#Plug_me%3a_Writing_your_own_plugins) to try and create a custom jQuery function but I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'foobar'

With the following code:

```
 jQuery.fn.foobar = function(options) {
   var settings = jQuery.extend({
     value: 5, name: "pete", bar: 655
   }, options);
 };


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").foobar();
});
```

**EDIT:**
I included the. It appears I had a link to jQuery twice. Once in the head and once in the body:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Some text</p>

    <script type='text/javascript' src="/js/quiz.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the above code(pre edit) happens to be running after DOMReady, $("p").foobar will be ran immediately, before $.fn.foobar is defined.

Comment: Where is this executed? Immediately in `<script>`? Or inside of a function/event of some sort?

Comment: @JanDvorak why should it be deleted?

Comment: @Sheldon at the very least, the previous heavily-upvoted but incorrect answers should be removed.

Comment: @JanDvorak I think what you've proposed is not fair. I've included links, laid out my code, explained myself etc. I think it contributes to the community.

Comment: @Sheldon I suggest you post the reason as an answer to your own question. Self-answers are perfectly valid, and I may give your answer a plus.

Comment: @Sheldon make it a proper question/answer pair, and will upvote the answer and I've undownvoted the question as well. Is this fair?

Comment: @Sheldon please notify me when you write an answer. I'm leaving for now.

Comment: @JanDvorak added an answer.

Comment: @Sheldon since I've promised you an upvote - here it is.

Answer (score 2):

After some time I found that I had included a link to jQuery twice; once in the header and once in the body. I removed the link in the body and this resolved the issue.

However, it is important to included jQuery before custom code. See [issue 2](http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/03/various-reasons-and-solutions-of-jquery.html) on this page.

Comment: You don't have to include it twice. Only once in the body should do. And load jQuery before your code, like you explained above.